# Object ob; and Object ob = new Object;

Tags: java, object

Please explain what is the difference between these two:

1)  `Object ob;`

2)  `Object ob = new Object();`

Comment: Please read a [Java tutorial on objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Comment: plate and plate with food

Comment: Also read this: http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp, it's pretty good.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I really like that analogy. I'd upvote that as an answer.

Comment: In  `Object ob;`, `ob` is a variable that can hold reference of an object of Object class. In Java you actually creates an instance of a class using `new` keyword dynamically. So in second declaration you assign `ob` the reference of instance of Object class, and now you can access methods and attributes of object after second declaration e.g. `ob.methodname()` (while just after first declaration you couldn't. `ob` in fist just a variable that doesn't refers to an actual object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is declared object:

```
Object ob;
```

Note that declarations do not instantiate objects. When object is declared, its value is initially set to null.

Second is declared and instantiated object:

```
Object ob = new Object();
```

In this case you are initialize new object of type Object over constructor methods.

Quick info you can get [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html). You can also get a lot of information in various java tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are only declaring the object, which, if it is an instance variable, will get initialized to null. In the second case, you are creating an "empty" `Object` instance which won't be `==` to null and therefore not the same thing. Often, it's not a good idea to leave an object to implicit initialization and you should explicitly initialize to something (even if it's null).

Answer (score 0):

The first creates a variable to hold a reference to an Object. By default, it will be initialized to null.

The second creates that variable, and initializes it to point to a newly created object. Though in fact you can't create an instance of Object, as I hope you're aware, since Object is abstract.

I've been saying this a lot recently, and I admit I'm biased, but there are some good tutorials  at [IBM's DeveloperWorks Java website](http://www.ibm.com/DeveloperWorks/java).

Answer (score 0):

1) is just declaration of an `Object` variable;
implicitly it is set to `null`

2) is declaration of an `Object` variable together with
its explicit initialization; the initialization is done
by a call to the `Object` default constructor